# reading and writing files (python, beginner here so easy code please!)

Tags: python, file

I was asked to open a file and put appended data under the following fields: username, firstname, surname, gender, year. I really don't know what's going on here please help.

```
studentfile = open("students.txt", "w")
print("this program writes Student data to \n Student text")
username = input("enter Student username, xxx to end:")

while username != "xxx":
    firstname = input("firstname: ")
    surname = input("surname: ")
    gender = input("Gender: ")
    year = input("Year: ")
    studentfile.write(username + "," + firstname + "," + surname + "," + gender + "," + year + "," + "\n")
    username = input("enter Student Username, xxx to end ")

print("%s, %s, %s, %s, %d" %(username, firstname, surname, gender, year))
```

Answer (score 0):

This program takes the user's input of username, firstname, surname, gender, and year and places it into a file called "students.txt".  The program is in a loop, which means it will continue asking for this information until the user enters their username as "xxx".

However, there is one little error.  The last line should be written as `print("%s, %s, %s, %s, %d" %(username, firstname, surname, gender, int(year)))` as %d refers to integers.